# Electronics - ISO 42v DC Brushless Fan to 110AC with Speed Knob MOD HELP

Tags: dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm looking to Mod a 42V DC brushless fan to work on an 110-AC outlet and incorporate a speed knob into the build.

This is the info that I have:

Fan was originally pulled from a Cisco 7600 Series Router Fan module; it's about 6 inches in diameter and has 4 wires coming from it.

Tag on the FAN: |
DC BRUSHLESS |
MODEL EFC1748DG |
DC48V 1.84A -4M41R |
(OPERATE: DC42V) |

Connecting Board Info: |
Yellow Wire = P |
Blue Wire = R |
Black Wire = - |
Red Wire = + |

Here is an Image of the fan:
[image: Brushless Motor Fan]

Comment: Here's a 48b power supply for $8 =) http://cgi.ebay.com/NEW-Original-CISCO-Power-Supply-AC-ADAPTER-48V-ADP-18FB-/390294921664?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5adf63e1c0

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

- Red is +48VDC
- Black is negative
- Blue is freq (rotation and lock signals)
- Yellow is PWM

All you need is a 5V PWM signal to control it and a 48v motor driver/power supply. Duty cycle should be 20KHz and to start it you should use a 30% PWM signal. If the yellow line disconnected it will rotate at full speed. everything else is in the datasheet.

[The Data Sheet](http://www.chipcatalog.com/Delta_Product_Groups/EFC1748DG-TP07.htm) has some good info on how to drive it correctly too.

on a side note you can use a 555 timer and a potentiometer(speed knob) to create the PWM.